# xrdp and xfce4 Ubuntu 14.04 slow refreshrate

Tags: 14.04, xfce, rdp, xrdp

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit and I am connecting via windows rdp to my ubuntu machine that has xrdp with xfce4 session. Network is 40mbps/5mbps. RDP to a windows machine from a windows machine is flawless from same location.

I can connect fine, but the refresh rate is horrible. When it fist opens the desktop, the picture drags as seen in this image. The same thing happens when items are opened, closed, etc. Windows have the same effect. Sometimes up to 4 seconds before the image is rendered, depending on the image.

Is there a setting to improve the refresh rate or something I can do to fix?

[image]

Comment: I didn't try xrdp but I had good luck w/ vnc. [install VNC Server on Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.namhuy.net/3106/install-vnc-server-ubuntu-14-04.html)

Comment: I went through all of these step with no luck, can't get a connection even with ports forwarded

Comment: tell me more about your setup? are you behind a router? dhcp?

Comment: Just a simple setup, ZyXel C1000Z modem/router, iSP = Centurylink 40mbps down/5mbps up, using noip.com for dynamic host routing. Prior setups with windows machines ran perfect

Answer (score 2):

This changes ll make little progress on this.

The performance can be increased by modifying the xrdp.ini file (backup process noted because backups are important).

Code:

```
sudo cp /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini /etc/xrdp/xrdp.back && sudo nano /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

In the [globals] section, change max_bpp=24 and add the command to use compression as so:

```
    max_bpp=128
    use_compression=yes
```

and modify the [xrdp7] section by changing xserver_bpp=24:

```
xserverbpp=128
```

Comment: 128 bit per pixel? U serious? Does not sound reasonable to me. Also I don't have "use_compression" in my ini file. There is bitmap_compression and bulk_compression, both are true by default